# Android Studio 2.2.3 Enabling and Disabling Offline Mode of Gradle

Tags: java, android

Please I am having this problem.I installed Android Studio 2.2.3 Its saying me 2 errors

**Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12 

Disable offline mode and Sync
Show in Project Structure dialog**

**Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1

Disable offline mode and Sync
Show in Project Structure dialog**

After I disabled the offline mode it says say that i should make it online.

**Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
Enable offline mode and Sync
Show in Project Structure dialog**

Please could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: connect to internet, disable offline mode and sync gradle

Comment: okay I Over came by removing junit from from the gradle. So will I face a problem? what is the benefit of using this junit?

Comment: set `use local gradle file` in your Android Studio when offline.

Comment: @MuletaAlem junit is for unit testing you will not face problem in your project